# Multiple _PublishedWebsites Folders

Tags: visual-studio-code, manjaro

I am using VS Code on Manjaro and have setup a solution with 2 projects, a webapp and a test project.

Each time I do a build it appears to generate a new _PublishedWebsites folder with NetCoreApp underneath it.  I am surprised that nobody else seems to have encountered this issue.  Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: i forgot to add; i am using appharbor and basically i am facing the same issue as this poster: https://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/93528-net-core-20-issue-with-publishdir - if i remove the publishdir line from my csproj then it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your `csproj` file, particularly `PublishDir` element which is your specified location for publishing output files and change that if your like.

However, I think this is required behavior for .net core support in app harbor, find more details in the support webpage over [here](https://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/90387-is-net-core-supported-yet#comment_42659267).